# Preventing heavy top layer of cake from crushing cream layer

Tags: cake, cream

I'm making a flourless cake with almond meal, thus quite dense, and it's also covered completely with whole cherries.

I thought I'd slice the cake horizontally and put a layer of cream in. The top layer will be quite heavy and I fear the cream will be squeezed out the sides. I wouldn't mind this too much normally, however I'll be transporting it in the springform tin I baked it in and suspect the squeezed out cream will smudge everywhere.

Just beat the cream until it's stiffer? Is there some additive that makes the cream firmer? The cream I was just planning on whipping it with confectioner's (icing) sugar and vanilla extract.

**Update:**

Gelatine method below worked perfectly with Australian Thickened Cream(35%, pre-thickened with Carrageenan and guar gum--I thought Aussie stuff was pre-thickened with gelatine?). Cream came out thick and did not squeeze out the sides when the heavy top layer was put on.

Comment: See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/29395/how-can-i-thicken-whipping-cream/29397#29397

Comment: Pillars. I use banana chunks or few other stable pieces to hold up a heavy layer. Not a real answer but heck, solves problem of ooze out the sides

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the whipped cream firmer, you could set it with gelatine or agar (which I think would be better unless the cake is being refrigerated until just before serving). For the recipe, I refer you to http://video.about.com/southernfood/How-to-Stabilize-Whipped-Cream.htm (video).

Having looked at the video, you might even want to add a half more of the gelatine/agar so it is really set (much like a pastry cream in a [fraisier](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=strawberry%20fraisier)).

Also, if a creamy filling is required could a pastry cream be used instead of whipped cream? It would set and cut much better (although would lose the lightness of whipped cream which you may be after - you could fold whipped egg whites or cream into it but then you have the same problem of it squeezing out).