# Piping whipped cream icing vs buttercream

Tags: whipped-cream, icing, frosting

I'm looking to try **piping** whipped cream icing, instead of buttercream -- what are the major ***handling differences*** the feel to it, different tips to use, any tricks or pitfalls I should be aware of? I've never done whipped cream icing before, but it was requested. I am used to a stiff buttercream, and would like to know the handling comparisons when piping it.

Comment: Oh, and I cannot use a meringue powder -- egg allergy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjusting whipped cream to hold its shape longer?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/33405/adjusting-whipped-cream-to-hold-its-shape-longer)

Comment: Actually, I was looking for some of the *piping* differences--feel to it, tips, any tricks or pitfalls I should be aware of--rather than just how to stabilize the icing, although that information is helpful, too..

Comment: I see. That is a different question.

Answer (score 4):

You could try adding a piping gel, such as the one found [here](http://www.webstaurantstore.com/wilton-704-105-clear-piping-gel/143704105.html?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=GoogleShopping&gclid=Cj0KEQiAwMLDBRDCh_r9sMvQ_88BEiQA6zuAQwovLzNUSqsngy7v7zKzBZ59OAx9GdUsRz58SoNnafgaAthd8P8HAQ), which contains no eggs or dairy.

Alternatively, the colder you keep the whipped cream icing, the better it will hold its shape. You could refrigerate the icing until immediately prior to serving which would help.

Answer (score 3):

The main pitfall to whipped cream is that it has to be kept cold. Your hands will heat up the cream in the bag, causing it to lose volume and pipe sloppily.

Stabilizing the whipped cream will help. See ([Adjusting whipped cream to hold its shape longer?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/33405/adjusting-whipped-cream-to-hold-its-shape-longer)) But mostly, you need to keep it cool:

- Frequent rests, putting the bag in the fridge
- Refill frequently
- Keep the extras in the refrigerator
- Don't let the room get too warm
- Refrigerate the result immediately.

Comment: I'd suggest combining the answers and keeping the parts you think are relevant. You can also repost your answer about stabilization on the other question and link to it.

Comment: The answers already there are adequate, so I just changed my answer to link to that question.

Comment: Hm, I don't see any of the alternative stabilizers (except cream cheese) mentioned there, so you might still have something to add!

Comment: I realized that when I went to delete the other answer, so I did indeed re-post that answer to the other question. Thank you for your help.