# Making 30% Sour Cream

Tags: baking, sour-cream

I only have regular sour cream but I need 30% sour cream. Can I add something to the sour cream to make it 30%?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Folks here will be able to help you a lot better if you can explain what kind of recipe you need the sour cream for, and what dairy/fats it already has in it.

Comment: Possibly relevant to you: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/48871/7180